# How to evaluate the limit: $\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{e^{it^2(1+y^2)}}{1+y^2} \, dy$

Tags: limits, analysis, solution-verification, parametric, fresnel-integrals

I was evaluating the Fresnel integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix^2}dx
$$

After some calculations, I successfully evaluated it correctly. However, there is one problem that I don't know how to evaluate strictly and not just logically. I want to evaluate this limit:

$$
\lim_{{t \to \infty}} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{it^2(1+y^2)}}{1+y^2} \, dy
$$

So, I have done this:

Let $y={x\over t}$, then our limit will become:

$$
\lim_{{t \to \infty}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{e^{it^2 \left(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}\right)}}{1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}} \frac{1}{t} \, dx
$$

Now, let's do something like this:

$$
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{{t \to \infty}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{e^{it^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2})}}{1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}} \frac{1}{t} \, dx \\
&= \lim_{{t \to \infty}} \left(\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\cos(t^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}))}{1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}} \frac{1}{t} \, dx + \int_{0}^{t} \frac{i\sin(t^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}))}{1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}} \frac{1}{t} \, dx\right)
\end{align*}
$$

Now, let's look at the first member and evaluate the limit for it:

$$
\lim_{{t \to \infty}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\cos(t^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}))}{1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}} \frac{1}{t} \, dx
$$

Instead of this integral, let's evaluate this kind of integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\left(\cos(t^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}))\right)^2}{(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2})^2} \frac{1}{t^2} \, dx
$$

Now, let's use the Dominated Convergence Theorem:

$$
\left| \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\left(\cos(t^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}))\right)^2}{(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2})^2} \frac{1}{t^2} \, dx \right| \leq \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2})^2} \frac{1}{t^2} \, dx
$$

As we evaluate the integral on the right side, it will give us:

$$
\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2})^2} \frac{1}{t^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi+2}{8t}
$$

So, we have:

$$
\left| \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\left(\cos(t^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}))\right)^2}{(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2})^2} \frac{1}{t^2} \, dx \right| \leq \frac{\pi+2}{8t}
$$

Now, let's take the limit on both sides, and we will get:

$$
\left| \lim_{{t \to \infty}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\left(\cos(t^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}))\right)^2}{(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2})^2} \frac{1}{t^2} \, dx \right| \leq 0
$$

And from this:

$$
\lim_{{t \to \infty}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\left(\cos(t^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}))\right)^2}{(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2})^2} \frac{1}{t^2} \, dx = 0
$$

And from this:

$$
\lim_{{t \to \infty}} \int_{{0}}^{{t}} \frac{{\cos(t^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}))}}{{1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}}} \cdot \frac{1}{t} \, dx = 0
$$
With the same logic, the second member is also $0$.
Therefore:

$$
\lim_{{t \to \infty}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{e^{it^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2})}}{1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}} \frac{1}{t} \, dx = 0
$$

But I can't properly explain why it was right to say if the limit of the integral from the square of the integrand function is $0$, then the limit of the integral from the integrand function (without the square) is also $0$. Can someone please explain this to me mathematically and not just logically? I know the first equation, which we desire to evaluate, oscillates very fast and therefore is zero, but I want to show all this mathematically, and I don't want to use the Gamma function.

Basically, we said that if:
$$
\lim_{{t \to \infty}} \int_{{0}}^{{t}} \left(f(x;t)\right)^2 \, dx = 0
$$
then:
$$
\lim_{{t \to \infty}} \int_{{0}}^{{t}} f(x;t) \, dx = 0
$$

But it isn't true for every function. Then, what makes it work in this case?

Thanks to everyone in advance who will try it.

Comment: Maybe BCS inequality will help: $\int_0^t |f|\: dx \le \int_0^t |f|^2 \: dx \int_0^t 1\: dx = t\int_0^t |f|^2 \: dx?$

Comment: @dsh  First of all thanks for the answer. I have tried it but didn't get the desired answer. beside isn't this CBS? and if so $g(x,t)=1$ should be incorrect shouldn't it? $g(x,t)$ has to depend on some $x$ and $t$ (I don't know if I'm correct) and if this is CBS then whole first member on the left side (included integral) of the inequality should be in modulus and in square and not just the $|f|$? if I am wrong can you explain BCS inequality more widely please?

Comment: I should admit I have no answer. I meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality.

Consider $\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\cos(t^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}))}{1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}} \frac{1}{t} \, dx$ and $f(x,t) =\frac{\cos(t^2(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}))}{1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}} \frac{1}{t}$ where $t$ is considered as parameter, for each $t > 0,$ $f(x,t)$ is integrable. Proceeding with estimations: $|\int_0^t f(x, t)\: dx| \le  \int_0^t 1 \cdot |f(x, t)|\: dx \le \sqrt{\int_0^t |f(x,t)|^2 \: dx} \sqrt{\int_0^t 1\: dx} = \sqrt{t}\sqrt{\int_0^t |f(x, t)|^2 \: dx} \le \sqrt{\pi + 2}.$

Comment: (cont.) The result is only that $|\int_0^t f(x, t)\: dx| \le \sqrt{\pi +2}$ uniformly on t. I do not understand how one applies $\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_0^t |f(x, t)|^2 \: dx = 0$ ignoring second factor on the left hand side of BCS inequality.

Comment: @dsh  I’m assuming I have mistake somewhere. As for BCS (?) inequality, yes if we take $g(x,t)=1$ it doesn’t help in any way evaluating the limit. Thanks for the idea which may lead to the right answer.

Comment: I simply do not know how reduce integral of $f$ to integral of $f^2$ without taking into account integral of $g(x,t)$ in BCS. It looks like dead end to me(. It's better look into provided solution)

Comment: Using the method of complex integration, it can be shown that
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{it^2 x}}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)} \, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt\pi}te^\frac{\pi i}4-\frac{i}{2\,t^2}e^{it^2}+\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\,t^3}e^{-\frac{\pi i}4}+O\left(\frac1{t^4}\right)$$
If this is relevant in your case, I can provide the solution.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I would love to see this evaluation if we can show that if $\lim_{{t \to \infty}}$ then whole expression on RHS goes to $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider $I(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{e^{it^2 x}}{\sqrt x(1+x)} \,dx$ . A typical way to solve such problems is to apply integration by part. But in this case, as @ Sangchul Lee mentioned, we cannot do this directly (we get terms diverging at $x=0$).

We can also apply complex integration. Let's consider a closed contour (a quarter-circle) in the complex plane; namely, introducing small $r>0$, we integrate along the following path $C$:
$$r\to1 \,(\text{along the real axis} \,X)\to i \,(\text{along the arch of the circle of the radius 1}\,(C_1))$$
$$\to ir\, (\text{along the imaginary axis} \,Y)\to r\,(\text{along the arch of the circle of the radius r}\,(C_2))$$
The function $f(z)=\frac{e^{it^2 z}}{\sqrt z(1+z)}$ is analytical inside the contour; therefore, $\oint_C f(z)dz=0$. Denoting also $I_r=\int_r^1 \frac{e^{it^2 x}}{\sqrt x(1+x)} \,dx$, we get the following equation:
$$I_r+\int_{C_1}\frac{e^{it^2 z}}{\sqrt z(1+z)}dz+\int_i^{ir}\frac{e^{it^2 z}}{\sqrt z(1+z)}dz+\int_{C_2}\frac{e^{it^2 z}}{\sqrt z(1+z)}dz=0\tag{0}$$
Next, we evaluate every integral
$$\bigg|\int_{C_2}\frac{e^{it^2 z}}{\sqrt z(1+z)}dz\bigg|=\bigg|\int_{\pi/2}^0\frac{e^{it^2 re^{i\phi}}}{\sqrt re^{i\phi/2}(1+re^{i\phi})}ire^{i\phi}d\phi\bigg|$$
$$<\int_0^{\pi/2}\bigg|\frac{e^{it^2 re^{i\phi}}}{\sqrt re^{i\phi/2}(1+re^{i\phi})}ire^{i\phi}\bigg|d\phi=\sqrt r\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{-t^2r\sin\phi}}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}d\phi<\sqrt r\int_0^{\pi/2}d\phi\to 0$$
$$=\frac\pi2\,\sqrt r\,\to 0\,\,\text{at}\,\,r\to 0\tag{1}$$
$$I_r=\int_r^1 \frac{e^{it^2 x}}{\sqrt x(1+x)} \,dx=\int_0^1 \frac{e^{it^2 x}}{\sqrt x(1+x)} \,dx-\int_0^r \frac{e^{it^2 x}}{\sqrt x(1+x)} \,dx$$
where
$$\bigg|\int_0^r \frac{e^{it^2 x}}{\sqrt x(1+x)} \,dx\bigg|<\int_0^r \bigg|\frac{e^{it^2 x}}{\sqrt x(1+x)}\bigg| \,dx=\int_0^r\frac{dr}{\sqrt r(1+r)}<\int_0^r\frac{dr}{\sqrt r}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt r}2\to 0\,\,\text{at}\,\,r\to 0$$
It means that
$$I_r\to I\,\,\text{at}\,\,r\to0\tag{2}$$
In the same way,
$$\int_i^{ir}\frac{e^{it^2 z}}{\sqrt z(1+z)}dz\overset{z=e^{\pi i/2}x}{=}-\,e^{\pi i/4}\int_r^1\frac{e^{-t^2x}}{\sqrt x(1+ix)}dx$$
$$=-\,e^{\pi i/4}\int_0^1\frac{e^{-t^2x}}{\sqrt x(1+ix)}dx+\,e^{\pi i/4}\int_0^r\frac{e^{-t^2x}}{\sqrt x(1+ix)}dx$$
$$\int_i^{ir}\frac{e^{it^2 z}}{\sqrt z(1+z)}dz\to -\,e^{\pi i/4}\int_0^1\frac{e^{-t^2x}}{\sqrt x(1+ix)}dx\,\,\text{at}\,\,r\to 0\tag{3}$$
Leading $r\to 0$ and using (1), (2), (3)
$$I=-\int_{C_1}\frac{e^{it^2 z}}{\sqrt z(1+z)}dz+\,e^{\pi i/4}\int_0^1\frac{e^{-t^2x}}{\sqrt x(1+ix)}dx\tag{4}$$
where
$$-\int_{C_1}\frac{e^{it^2 z}}{\sqrt z(1+z)}dz=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{it^2e^{i\phi}}ie^{i\phi}}{e^{i\phi/2}(1+e^{i\phi})}d\phi$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}\frac{i\,e^{-i\phi}e^{it^2e^{i\phi}}}{2t^2\cos\frac\phi2}\,\bigg|_{\phi=0}^{\phi=\frac\pi2}+\frac i{2t^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{-i\phi}e^{it^2e^{i\phi}}}{\cos\frac\phi2}\left(i-\frac{\sin\frac\phi2}{2\cos^2\frac\phi2}\right)d\phi$$
$$=-\,\frac i{2t^2}+\frac{e^{-t^2}}{\sqrt 2t^2}+\frac i{2t^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{-i\phi}e^{it^2e^{i\phi}}}{\cos\frac\phi2}\left(i-\frac{\sin\frac\phi2}{2\cos^2\frac\phi2}\right)d\phi$$
The remaining integral is regular and at least $\sim\frac1{t^2}$ (integrating by part again we can show that it $\sim\frac1{t^4}$)
$$-\int_{C_1}\frac{e^{it^2 z}}{\sqrt z(1+z)}dz=O\left(\frac1{t^2}\right)\tag{5}$$

And the last integral
$$e^{\pi i/4}\int_0^1\frac{e^{-t^2x}}{\sqrt x(1+ix)}dx\overset{s=t^2x}{=}\frac{e^{\pi i/4}}t\int_0^{t^2}\frac{e^{-s}}{\sqrt s(1+\frac{is}{t^2})}ds$$
$$=\frac{e^{\pi i/4}}t\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-s}}{\sqrt s(1+\frac{is}{t^2})}ds-\frac{e^{\pi i/4}}t\int_{t^2}^\infty\frac{e^{-s}}{\sqrt s(1+\frac{is}{t^2})}ds$$
where
$$\bigg|\frac{e^{\pi i/4}}t\int_{t^2}^\infty\frac{e^{-s}}{\sqrt s(1+\frac{is}{t^2})}ds\bigg|<\frac1t\int_{t^2}^\infty\frac{e^{-s}}tds=\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t^2}\tag{6}$$
and
$$\frac{e^{\pi i/4}}t\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-s}}{\sqrt s(1+\frac{is}{t^2})}ds=\frac{e^{\pi i/4}}t\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-s}}{\sqrt s}ds+\frac{e^{\pi i/4}}t\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\left(\frac1{\sqrt s(1+\frac{is}{t^2})}-\frac1{\sqrt s}\right)ds=$$
$$=\frac{e^{\pi i/4}}t\sqrt\pi+\frac{e^{-\pi i/4}}{t^3}\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\frac{\sqrt s}{1+\frac{is}{t^2}}ds=\frac{e^{\pi i/4}\sqrt \pi}t+O\left(\frac1{t^3}\right)\tag{7}$$
In fact, repeating the procedure we can show that $(7)=\frac{e^{\pi i/4}\sqrt\pi}t+\frac{e^{-\pi i/4}\sqrt\pi}{2t^3}+O\left(\frac1{t^5}\right)$

Putting (5), (6) and (7) into (4)
$$I=\frac{e^{\pi i/4}\sqrt \pi}t+O\left(\frac1{t^2}\right)$$
The limit follows.

Answer (score 5):

**New Answer.** Since OP seems not aware of Lebesgue theory of integrals, let me switch to a more elementary means.

*Key Idea.* The basic idea is to note that

$$ \int y e^{it^2y^2} \, \mathrm{d}y = \frac{e^{it^2y^2}}{2it^2} $$

is bounded by $t^{-2}$, which vanishes as $t \to \infty$. So, if we apply integration by parts to OP's integral, we will end up with something that decays as $t \to \infty$, hinting that the limit is zero. Due to some technicality involved, however, I will implement this idea only indirectly.

*Evaluation.* We begin by noting that

$$ \frac{1}{1+y^2} = y \biggl( \frac{1}{2} + \int_{y}^{1} \frac{1+3x^2}{x^2(1+x^2)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr). $$

Now let $I(t) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{it^2(1+y^2)}}{1+y^2} \, \mathrm{d}y$ denote OP's integral. Plugging the above identity to $I(t)$ and switching the order of integration using Fubini's theorem,

\begin{align*}
I(t)
&= e^{it^2} \int_{0}^{1} e^{it^2y^2} y  \biggl( \frac{1}{2} + \int_{y}^{1} \frac{1+3x^2}{x^2(1+x^2)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= e^{it^2} \biggl( \frac{1}{2}\biggl[ \int_{0}^{1} e^{it^2y^2} y  \, \mathrm{d}y \biggr] + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+3x^2}{x^2(1+x^2)^2} \biggl[ \int_{0}^{x} e^{it^2y^2} y  \, \mathrm{d}y \biggr] \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr).
\end{align*}

To this end, we define the function $\varphi(\xi)$ by

$$ \varphi(\xi) = \int_{0}^{1} e^{i\xi s}  \, \mathrm{d}s = \frac{e^{i\xi} - 1}{i\xi}. $$

Then $|\varphi(\xi)| \leq \int_{0}^{1} |e^{i\xi s}| \, \mathrm{d}s = 1 $ and $\varphi(\xi) \to 0$ as $|\xi| \to \infty$. Moreover, by substituting $y = \sqrt{s}$ for the first integral and $y = x\sqrt{s}$ for the second integral, OP's integral becomes

\begin{align*}
I(t)
&= e^{it^2} \biggl( \frac{\varphi(t^2)}{4} + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+3x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} \varphi(x^2 t^2) \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr).
\end{align*}

If OP is aware of Dominated Convergence Theorem, the above equality immediately gives the desired answer by switching the order of $\lim_{t\to\infty}$ and $\int_{0}^{1} \ldots \, \mathrm{d}x$. Otherwise, we can still resolve the problem by elementary means.

Fix $\eta \in (0, 1)$ and note that

\begin{align*}
|I(t)|
&\leq \frac{|\varphi(t^2)|}{4} + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+3x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} |\varphi(x^2 t^2)| \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\leq \frac{|\varphi(t^2)|}{4} + \int_{0}^{\eta} \frac{1+3x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x + \Bigl( \sup_{s \geq \eta^2 t^2}|\varphi(s)| \Bigr) \int_{\eta}^{1} \frac{1+3x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Taking $\limsup$ as $t \to \infty$, we get

\begin{align*}
\limsup_{t\to\infty} |I(t)|
&\leq \int_{0}^{\eta} \frac{1+3x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Since the LHS is independent of $\eta$, letting $\eta \to 0^+$ yields $\displaystyle \limsup_{t\to\infty} |I(t)| = 0$ and we are done.

---

**Old Answer.** The limit in the title and the body are different, so I will assume the one in the body is correct.

Substituting $x = y^2$,

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{it^2(1+y^2)}}{1+y^2} \, \mathrm{d}y
= e^{it^2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{it^2 x}}{2\sqrt{x}(1+x)} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

By the [Riemann–Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma), the integral converges to $0$:

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{it^2 x}}{2\sqrt{x}(1+x)} \, \mathrm{d}x = 0. $$

Since the prefactor $e^{it^2}$ is bounded, this means that the entire expression converges to $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, my bad, I have corrected (edited) the title. limit in the body is correct as you assumed. I will analyze everything out here and will comment if I’ll have further questions if you don’t mind. Again thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry I’m little bit newbie at this. Can you explain and show how this integral converges to $0$ by Riemann–Lebesgue lemma? Beside that everything is understandable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Nebula, Riemann–Lebesgue lemma tells that if you have an integrable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ (where integrability means that $f$ is measurable and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x<\infty$), then $$\lim_{\xi\to\pm\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{i\xi x}\,\mathrm{d}x=0.$$ Now you may let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}(1+x)},&0<x<1\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and check that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: I'm sorry, looks like I don't know some details which will help me to fully understand the evaluation of the whole problem with this. I still didn't cover Lebesgue at the university and I am learning it now on my own. Also I was unable to find helpful resources for this problem. If you don't mind, can you show me fully detailed evaluation of this? also in the theorem we have infinites in the limits of integral but in our integral limits are finite ($0$ and $1$) and how does it help us and how are we using this Lemma in our case. Thank you in advance and sorry for the bothering.

Comment: my lecturer asked me to do this evaluation of the Fresnel Integral but also demanding on detailed evaluation of this limit which is my only problem. I would be really grateful if you could write this evaluation fully detailed so I can analyze and learn everything out without missing any small detail. Thank you in advance again

Comment: @Nebula, My old answer, assuming you have learned Lebesgue's theory of integration contains all the necessary information. On the other hand, if you are not aware of this theory, it may be best if we avoid them. I revamped my answer so it is within the scope of preliminary analysis.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood everything, but there is one thing I want to make sure. At the end in the $\sup(|φ(s)|)$, we defined $s$ as  $s \ge (η^2)(t^2)$. Why do we need $η^2$ here? Why can’t we just say      $s \ge t^2$? And what is the purpose of taking $\sup()$? Just to make sure that the output is a number? And also, instead of just taking $\lim$, why are we taking $\lim \sup()$?
Again, thank you so much.